# AS3 Code - Sound not playing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, mp3

I'm trying to play sound in as3 code using an external mp3 file.

So here's the code I am using:

```
    private function playSound():void
    {
        trace("loading sound");
        var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
        mySound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError);
        mySound.load(new URLRequest("Menu.mp3"));
        mySound.play();
        trace("playing sound");
    }

    private function handleIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        //handle error if needed
    }
```

The music just doesn't play at all.

The traces "loading sound" and "playing sound" appear so the code is being run.

The mp3 file Menu.mp3 is in the same folder as the .fla file used to run the project. Is this the correct directory? I tried moving it around but still couldnt play the sound.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your code seemed to work for me. Can you try `trace( mySound.play() );`? That should return a SoundChannel object, but it might be null if there is a problem with your sound card.

Comment: trace( mySound.play() ); output this - [object SoundChannel]. Hm not sure what the problem is then, so an mp3 was actually playing for you with that code?

Comment: Yup, I just copied your playSound() code to the timeline as a quick test, and it played an mp3 okay. I have heard of Flash having trouble with high bitrate mp3s though, do any errors show up if you try importing the file to the library?

Comment: Could you give your Main.mp3, I also checked your code - it works!

Comment: Sure, here's a link you can download the mp3 from - http://picosong.com/3TyC

Comment: Odd, that file seems to work fine for me too, though it is rather quiet. The only other thing I can think to try is to add `var sc:SoundChannel = mySound.play()` then trace the sound channel's leftPeak and rightPeak properties on an ENTER_FRAME loop, to see if it is actually playing something that just isn't audible for some reason.

Comment: @David Mear, Have your successful tests been carried out within a class or other type of closure?

Comment: I was testing directly on the timeline, but I just tried moving the same code to a class and instantiating that, and it worked as before.

Comment: Ah, it may be obvious, but the file I downloaded from your link was just called "Menu", so I added ".mp3" to get it to load. Flash threw a SecurityError instead of an IOError in that case, but still produced a SoundChannel object, so might that be the problem?

Comment: Hm, tried both of your suggestions. Making the enter frame loop and tracing leftPeak and rightPeak - they were always 0 so at least I know no audio is being played. I also tried changing the file name to Menu.mp3, didnt have any effect. I've got a couple other ideas to try, will post here if anything works ^^. And thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry I've only been able to suggest more tests! Does sc.position increase properly as the file plays? (It stays at zero if the file hasn't loaded.) Also, is it possible the swf has been muted somewhere using `SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);`?

Comment: Ok, the position stays at 0 so that narrows it down a bit. Didnt find any code elsewhere that muted the swf.

Comment: Oh wow, just found that in another class the swf was muted xD. It was a class that I didn't even know existed written by someone else on the project. Thanks a ton for your help David, you are a total boss!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. I was wondering if the swf might be in a different folder, but hopefully it was just that sneaky mute!

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions that might help:

1. Declare mySound as a class level property. The garbage collector might be disposing of the variable prematurely since it is local.
2. mySound.play() returns a SoundChannel object. Try storing this in a class level property.
3. Add an event listener to the sound for Event.COMPLETE, right before loading the sound. Try playing the sound after this event occurs. As it is, you might be trying to play the sound before it has loaded.

```
    private var mySound:Sound;
    private var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel;

    private function playSound():void
    {
        mySound = new Sound();
        mySound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError);
        mySound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadCompletion);
        mySound.load(new URLRequest("Menu.mp3"));
    }

    private function handleLoadCompletion(evt:Event):void
    {
        mySoundChannel = mySound.play();
    }

    private function handleIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        //handle error if needed
    }
```

**Edit:**
After reviewing [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load%28%29), I think that suggestion 3 isn't necessary.

Comment: Tried each one but still no sound, thanks for your suggestions though!